# Office Add-in command ExecuteFunction action not running word.run

Tags: office-js

I wanted to use the Office Add-in Commands in my add-in. I have used
[this example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/Simple) as a template.

I planned to change the `ExecuteFunction` button to run a function which adds a new string into the document. So I changed the `writeText` function and the code is listed below.

When I click the button, nothing happens.  What might cause this?

**-- Update --**

I was struggling to debug this - didn't find a way to do this with F12 because it is not loaded through the browser as a task pane.
Finally debugged in throw visual studio - the problem was that I have used : Office.context.document.body instead of the context parameter of the function directly.

The issue can be closed.
Thank you all!

**------------------------------**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <!--During development turn off caching-->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
        (function () {
            Office.initialize = function (reason) {
                //If you need to initialize something you can do so here. 
            };
        })();

        function writeText(event) {
            Word.run(function (context) {
                    var body = Office.context.document.body;
                    body.insertText('Test', 'Start');
                    return context.sync();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                    }
                });
            event.completed();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Function file body is never displayed.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried verifying whether any of the other code is running and whether Office.initialize is firing (by debugging using breakpoints and/or console.log)?

Comment: Could you add your manifest file to your question as well?

Comment: Found the problem - updated the issue,
Thank you all!